# Obtener la fecha del sistema con el software BadBoy para testing

Tags: javascript, date, pruebas-unitarias

Estoy creando un script para las pruebas automatizadas de una aplicacion, para exportarlo y usarlo con JMeter para realizar pruebas de estres.

Necesitaría obtener la fecha del sistema como una variable, a nivel de script, no del entorno, pero no puedo hacerlo de ninguna manera.

¿Algún consejo?

Gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen varias formas de obtener la fecha actual, una puede ser

```
<script>
var f = new Date();
document.write(f.getDate() + "/" + (f.getMonth() +1) + "/" + f.getFullYear());
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, el problema que tengo es incorporar esa fecha , que con el new Date() valdría creo, en una variable de una rutina de badboy

Comment: Ve si esto te puede servir http://www.badboysoftware.biz/docs/variables_and_looping.htm

Comment: Muchas gracias, a raíz de ese enlace, con tu script, y el enlace de la parte inferior de variables automáticas lo he conseguido. Para ello, cree al inicio del script de badboy un script js con el código que me indicaste (Al comienzo del step, Add/JScript). con el siguiente contenido:


var f = new Date();
var fString = f.getDate() + "/" + (f.getMonth() +1) + "/" + f.getFullYear();
badboy.setVariable("sysdate",fString)


Para usarlo desde el script badboy ${sysdate} y todo perfecto. muchas gracias.

Comment: Por nada, me alegra haber sido de ayuda.